# Java error - Cannot find symbol

Tags: java

I am used to writing in C++, and I just can't figure out these Java errors. I appreciate any help or advice. Here is my code:

```
public class Grade {

    public int inputScore() {
        int testScore;
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Letter Grade Converter");
        System.out.println("Enter numberical grade:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        testScore = sc.nextInt();
        return testScore;
    }

    public String assignLetter() {
        String grade;
        if (testScore >= 88) {
            grade = "A";
        } else if (testScore >= 80) {
            grade = "B";
        } else if (testScore >= 67) {
            grade = "C";
        } else if (testScore >= 60) {
            grade = "D";
        } else if (testScore >= 0) {
            grade = "F";
        }
        return grade;
    }

    public String printResult() {
        System.out.println("Letter grade:" + grade);
    }
}
```

Along with my driver class:

```
public class GradeApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Grade studentGrade = new Grade();  // create student object
        String choice = "y";
        while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            studentGrade.inputScore();  //get score from user and assign it to the variable
            studentGrade.assignLetter(); //assign a letter grade based on the score
            studentGrade.printResult();  //display the letter grade
        }
    }
}
```

Neither will compile. I can't seem to figure out why.

I am used to using the relational operator "::" in C++, which references the driver code to the classes in the other code. I was wondering how to do that in Java. It keeps giving me a "cannot find symbol" error on the `grade` variable at the very bottom as well as at all the `testScore` instances.

Comment: Post the actual, entire error message. Java doesn't separate `::` and `.`; nearly anywhere in C++ where you'd use `::`, you'll use `.`.

Answer (score 3):

You've got 2 methods

```
public int inputScore()
{
    int testScore;
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Letter Grade Converter");
    System.out.println("Enter numberical grade:");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    testScore =sc.nextInt();
    return testScore;

}
```

and

```
public String assignLetter()
{
    String grade;
    if (testScore >= 88) {
            grade = "A";
    }   else if (testScore >=80){
            grade = "B";
    }   else if (testScore >=67){
            grade = "C";
    }   else if (testScore >=60){
            grade = "D";
    }   else if (testScore >= 0){
            grade = "F";
    }
    return grade;
}
```

In the first method, you declare a variable called `testScore`. You don't do that in the second one. Where do you expect that variable to come from?

Variable declared in methods have scope that extends only to anything after it in that method.

You could make `testScore` an [instance variable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) if you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the variables you're using aren't in the scope of the methods. Try using this. Although I would like to argue that there are much better ways to pull this off simply using a static class or something like that.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Grade
{
    private int testScore;
    private String grade;

    public int inputScore()
    {
        int testScore;
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Letter Grade Converter");
        System.out.println("Enter numberical grade:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        testScore =sc.nextInt();
        return testScore;

    }
    public String assignLetter()
    {

            if (testScore >= 88) {
            grade = "A";
            }   else if (testScore >=80){
            grade = "B";
            }   else if (testScore >=67){
            grade = "C";
            }   else if (testScore >=60){
            grade = "D";
            }   else if (testScore >= 0){
            grade = "F";
        }
        return grade;
    }
    public String printResult()
    {
        System.out.println ("Letter grade:" + grade);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really a problem of [variable scope](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html).  Your variables `testScore` and `grade` won't exist outside of the methods `inputScore()` and `assignLetter()`, respectively.

What you intend to do is declare these as member variables instead:

```
public class Grade {
    private int testScore;
    private String grade;

    // methods (omitted for brevity)
```

...and then, you'll have to initialize them in your constructor.

```
public Grade() {
    testScore = 0;
    grade = "";
}
```

As an aside, and ever-so-slightly orthogonal to the main issue, I'm of the opinion that `inputScore()` should be accepting an argument of type `int` to it, instead of controlling both the input from the user and assignment.  It's also *extremely* weird to return the value immediately after, especially when your driver throws the value away.

Answer (score 0):

Test score is not reachable by second method, However if you declared testscore as  object inside the class 
Or if you declared it as a static variable it will work